# Cannot push to my clones repository

Tags: git, github

I have seen a lot of questions about this, but a lot of them are outdated and the rest refer to different peculiarities of this same issue. I am sorry if I could not spot a similar question in case I am creating a duplicate.

I have just cloned a repository that I created.

```
git clone https://github.com/mygituser/myproj.git
```

I can `git add` and `git commit`. But when I go `git push origin master` authentication fails like this:

```
[user@mach myproj]$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': mygituser
Password for 'https://mygituser@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mygituser/myproj.git/'
```

These are my origins:

```
[user@mach myproj]$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/mygituser/myproj.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/mygituser/myproj.git (push)
```

My Git user is `mygituser`, I also set my username and password:

```
git config --global user.name "mygituser"
git config --global user.email "XXX@gmail.com"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is a clone from the original or from a fork? if it is a clone from original repo you cant just push to it without having push it to the fork version first and making a merge request

Comment: It is on my original repo. Not a fork, it is just a repository I created from Git on web, I cloned it on my Linux machine and the rest you know.

Comment: Is `mygituser` your *github* username? Can you successfully use that username and password to log into the github website?  In general, I find it easier to use `ssh` public key authentication to access repositories, but either should work.  This really just looks like you're entering the wrong userid or password.

Comment: It is, but now that you mention it, I logged out and then in again and I have 2 factor auth... is this a possible problem? However still strange, I have another repo and I develop on Windows (in this question I am on a Unix machine working on another repository i created) where I use the GUI Git program. There I have no problems.

Comment: This is my same problem, I dont have two factor auth enabled. I can login with the same credentials. What ever I do, I just cant push. Whats wrong with these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in a comment you have 2 factor authentication enabled. This requires you to create an access token rather than use your password. https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/ explains how to do this and will probably be more up to date than this answer.

1. In the top right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click **Settings**.
2. In the user settings sidebar, click **Personal access tokens**.
3. Click **Generate new token**.
4. Give your token a descriptive name.
5. Select the scopes you wish to grant to this token. The default scopes allow you to interact with public and private repositories, user data, and gists.
6. Click **Generate token**.
7. Copy the token to your config as password. For security reasons, after you navigate off this page, no one will be able to see the token again.

Comment: Ok I see, gonna try this and let you know. Thanks